# update missing values in Python Pandas dataframe with matching conditions

Tags: python, pandas, match

I have a dataframe `df1` with 3 columns (A,B,C), NaN represents missing value here

```
A     B      C  
1     2    NaN
2     1    2.3
2     3    2.5
```

I have a dataframe `df2` with 3 columns (A,B,D)

```
A     B     D
1     2     2
2     1     2
2     3     4
```

The expected output would be

```
A     B      C
1     2      2
2     1      2.3
2     3      2.5
```

I want to have values in column C in `df1` **intact** if not missing, replaced by corresponding value in D with other two columns value equal, i.e, `df1.A==df2.A` and `df1.B==df2.B`

any good solution?

Comment: Also, add sample `df2` and expected output like `df1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use the columns A and B as the index. If you use fillna then, pandas will align the indices and give you the correct result:

```
df1.set_index(['A', 'B'])['C'].fillna(df2.set_index(['A', 'B'])['D']).reset_index()
Out: 
   A  B    C
0  1  2  2.0
1  2  1  2.3
2  2  3  2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
In [100]: df['C'] = np.where((np.isnan(df.C))&(df.A==df1.A)&(df.B==df1.B),df1.D,df.C)

In [101]: df
Out[101]: 
     A    B    C
0  1.0  2.0  2.0
1  2.0  1.0  2.3
2  2.3  1.2  2.5
```

`np.where` is faster when compared:

```
In [102]: %timeit df['C'] = np.where((np.isnan(df.C))&(df.A==df1.A)&(df.B==df1.B),df1.D,df.C)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.3 ms per loop


In [103]: %timeit df.set_index(['A', 'B'])['C'].fillna(df1.set_index(['A', 'B'])['D']).reset_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 5.92 ms per loop
```

Comment: This will only work if df1 and df2 have the same length, and common observations are in the same order. `df1['C'].fillna(df2['D'])`  would work in that case too.

Comment: yes, what if df1 and df2 does not have the same length?

Comment: @ayhan I have not thought about that i will try and let you know. Thank you for pointing out the mistake.